# How to get the Locale settings like country-code in App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

I am developing yet another bmi app and I want it to be useful also for Americans using non-SI units like foot and pound. But I don't like to add an extra button to switch between units. I would rather use the system settings to automate that. The class `java.utils.locale` seems to be useful. But how do I access that in my App Inventor program?

Answer (score 0):

use the [tools extension](https://puravidaapps.com/tools.php) and its Country and/or Language method

[image]

Returns the country/region code of the current Locale, which should either be the empty string, an uppercase ISO 3166 2-letter code, or a UN M.49 3-digit code.

[image]

Returns the language code of the current Locale.